# What will be the next key?

Tags: pattern

- Thursday 23rd: BKOV
- Friday 24th: BLRS
- Saturday 25th: BMTZ
- Sunday 26th: BOMW
- Monday 27th: CFPT
- Tuesday 28th: BKPU
- Wednesday 29th: BGOW

Answer (score 4):

Could it be

> Thursday 30th: BKOV, since the keys could repeat every week?

Comment: El-Guest, is this another of your *`Cheater-Pants-You-Can't-Do-That`* solutions? :D Great answer either way!

Comment: @PerpetualJ they're still my favourite types of solution! I'd be interested to see what the correct answer is though (even if it's this! ;P)

Comment: I second that motion; I've tried running a few algorithms over the sequence. I even went as far as converting to hexadecimal and seeing if there was some mathematical relationship to no avail.

Comment: @El-Guest great answer but the key dosen't repeat every week